# Is it Ok to use C# 8.0 with .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms

Im creating Winform app that targets .NET 3.5. I have enabled C# 8.0 in the project file.

The main reason i used c# 8.0 is to use `delegate void OnSomeEvent(object obj, string name);` which i cant use in c# 7.3

[image]

[image]

The Interface is used by classes that are unknown at runtime. I want to use the interface to search and cast those classes usinf reflection then subscribe to the event they inherited.

So is it ok to use C# 8.0 with .NET 3.5?

Comment: C# v8 was the first version of C# that required changes in the CLR.  Most of all possible thanks to CoreCLR, the version of the CLR that powers .NET5+.  You'll be flying without a safety net, it isn't obvious to me that the legacy CLR will generate an exception.  Try using the default interface method feature for example.

Comment: @NineBerry I have added screenshot

Comment: It thinks you're trying to declare a default interface implementation (i.e. a method belonging to the interface). Move it outside of the interface and it will compile.

Comment: Your latest image (please include code as _text_) still doesn't explain why the delegate itself has to be declared within the interface.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I want classes that inherit the interface to implement the event

Comment: Yes, the _event_, not the _delegate_. My question is about why the delegate has to be declared within the interface, not why the event has to be.

Comment: The event uses the delegate signature. I dont know any other way to do

Comment: Move the delegate outside of the interface. Problem solved.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Outside where?

Comment: Just before the interface within the namespace that the interface is also part of. See the updated answer

Comment: Either you post and accept your own answer, or accept answers from others. Never edit the question to include something like that as that's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama and NineBerry Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain features in newer versions of the C# language require the presence of specific classes at runtime. when you use these features, your application will not compile or fail during linking or at runtime.

An example is tuples that require the presence of the `ValueTuple<>` class.

---

With regard to the specific question: According to [The history of C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history)

> Default interface members require enhancements in the CLR.

So, you won't be able to use default interface methods with the 3.5 version of .net Framework.

However, in your example you just have a delegate declaration. You don't need to put the delegate declaration inside the interface. You can just put it before or after the interface declaration since delegates can be declared inside a namespace directly.

The event itself can be declared inside the interface, even in earlier versions of C#.

```
delegate void OnSomeEvent(object obj, string name);

public interface IUpdate
{
    event OnSomeEvent SomeEvent;
}
```

Comment: If i dont use those classes will it still have effects? or are u suggesting to use lower version?
the reason i used c# 8.0 is to use  `delegate void OnSomeEvent(object ob, string name);` which i cant use in c# 7.3

Comment: You can use some newer syntax without problems (for example basic pattern matching) but will not be able to use some newer syntax that builds on classes in the runtime (like for example tuples). The list of syntax improvements is too big to make a complete list.

Comment: To avoid any problem i will go back to C# 7.3. But is there any hack to do the same thing in 7.3 which will have same result. I need to declare the delegate within the interface.

Comment: @ahba Why do you _need to_ declare the delegate in the interface?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The interface is inherited by some classes which are unknown at runtime. Im using the interface to search and cast them using Reflection then use the delegate.

Comment: @ahba Can you show a small scale example of that in your question?